# Firefox Touchscreen in Ubuntu 20.04 with Wayland

Tags: firefox, 20.04, touchscreen, wayland

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Wayland (for fractional scaling) on a laptop with touchscreen. I would like to use firefox with touch-scrolling. In Ubuntu 19.10, I needed to modify the environment variable `GDK_BACKEND=wayland`.  In 20.04, this setting does not work and firefox does not start. I just get the terminal output:

```
(firefox:10489): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:44:22.416: cannot open display: :0
```

I also tried `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` and `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` but firefox keeps using x11 as window protocol (shown in about:support). How can I make firefox use wayland?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate this on Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome Session (Wayland), Firefox 77.0.1. I am however able to replicate it perfectly - the non-start, the terminal output - by logging in to the default Ubuntu session, which is still X-based.

The obvious question then is how sure you are that you really are on Wayland? Run the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` from the command line. The response is `wayland` on the GNOME session (don't know if it works the Ubuntu on Wayland session).

You can install the "Gnome" session as the package gnome-session and select it from the settings pop menu in the lower right corner (assuming GDM), once you start typing in your password on the login screen. Or just try "Ubuntu on wayland" from the same menu.